# AnimatedSwitcher with Column jumping animation bug

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I am using an `AnimatedSwitcher` but when the `child` is switching there is a *jumping* that should not happen.

Here is a [Screenvideo](https://gofile.io/d/TngtCj) for a better understanding.

That is my code:

```
return AnimatedSwitcher(
  duration: defaultAnimationDurationForWidget * 5,
  child: coursesState.when(
    loading: () {
      return Column(
        key: const Key('loading'),
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ...List.generate(
            2,
            (index) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 20,
              ),
              child: SkeletonAvatar(
                style: SkeletonAvatarStyle(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 75,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    defaultBorderRadius,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
    },
    success: (courses, lastPlayedCourse) {
      return Column(
        key: const Key('success'),
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: 20,
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: 75,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Palette.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
```

As you can see I already added `Keys` because both children are `Columns`.

I have no idea why this happens. Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the defaultLayoutBuilder which is default for AnimatedSwitcher.

```dart
static Widget defaultLayoutBuilder(Widget? currentChild, List<Widget> previousChildren) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        ...previousChildren,
        if (currentChild != null) currentChild,
      ],
    );
  }
```

Here while switching out, both the widgets are added to stack with alignment = Alignment.center

If you change this to Alignment.topCenter, the jump will be fixed.
So add

```dart
layoutBuilder: (currentChild, previousChildren) {
        return Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            ...previousChildren,
            if (currentChild != null) currentChild,
          ],
        );
      },
```

to AnimatedSwitcher.

Your issue will be fixed.

Comment: never thought about `layoutBuilder`! Working as expected now, thank you :)